# Is $f(x) = \sum_n \frac{\sin{(x/n)}}{n}$ continuous over $]-1,1[\subset\mathbb{R}$? Is it derivable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, continuity

I tried to prove both propositions, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is valid. My main concern is to know if it is a formally correct proof, but I would appreciate any answer or comment improving it. Here goes my try.

#### Continuity

$$
\forall x\geq0\in\mathbb{R}, n\in\mathbb{N^*}: \sin{x} \leq x \Rightarrow \sin{\frac{x}{n}} \leq \frac{x}{n} \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{n}\sin{\frac{x}{n}} \leq \frac{x}{n^2}
$$

and $\sum_n\frac{x}{n^2}$ converges for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so by Weierstrass criterion we can conclude that

$$
\exists f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\ \forall x\geq0\in\mathbb{R}:\ \sum_n \frac{\sin{(x/n)}}{n} \rightrightarrows f(x)
$$

On other hand, because $\sin{-x}=-\sin{x}$ it follows that the above can be expanded to any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which implies that $f(x)$ is uniformly convergent over $]-1,1[$ and therefore continuous.

#### Derivability

First

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin{(x/n)}}{n} = \frac{\cos{(x/n)}}{n^2}
$$

and by an argument analog to the one applied to $\sin{x}$ we conclude

$$
\exists g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\ \forall x\in]-1,1[\subset\mathbb{R}:
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_n \frac{\sin{(x/n)}}{n} = \sum_n \frac{\cos{(x/n)}}{n^2} \rightrightarrows g(x)
$$

This, together with the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous, implies that $f(x)$ is derivable over $]-1,1[$ and that

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_n \frac{\sin{(x/n)}}{n} = f'(x) \ \ \ \ \square
$$

Comment: three comments: if you have a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n$ which converge to a limit $f$ and their derivatives $f_n'$ also converge to a limit function $g$ you <b>cannot</b> infer, that $f=g$; you can see wikipedia for counter examples and sufficient conditions.
Second, for continuity you need uniform continuity, which you did not mention in your argumentation.
Third and minor: please always mention over which variable you take your limits; if you use $\sum_n$ for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ and also use $\sum_n h_n \rightarrow f$ then what are you taking your limit over in the latter?

Comment: @Targon To your first comment, I guess you are saying that my reasoning it not sufficient to infer that $f'=g$, right? You seem to have forgotten the apostrophe. About the second and third:  I will be more explicit, once I will be able to find sufficient conditions. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: you are right, what I meant was "you cannot infer that $f'=g$".